# Command output parsing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a Python script on Windows 7, which reads the output of command `ipconfig /displaydns` and try to get some values from the output.

The output of `ipconfig /displaydns"`is something like this,

```
Windows IP Configuration

9.a.c.e.x-0.19-430f5091.531.1518.1b8d.2f4a.210.0.k1m2t5a3245k242qmfp75spjkv.avts.

Record Name . . . . . : 9.a.c.e.x-0.19-430f5091.531.1518.1b8d.2f4a.210.0.k1m2t5a3245k242qmfp75spjkv.avts.
Record Type . . . . . : 1
Time To Live  . . . . : 294
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Answer
A (Host) Record . . . : 127.0.0.16
```

I am taking this output and saving it in a variable as below,

```
output = subprocess.check_output("ipconfig /displaydns", shell=True)
```

When I print "output" I get the following

```
b'\r\nWindows IP Configuration\r\n\r\n   9.a.c.e.x-0.19-430f5091.531.1518.1b8d.2f4a.210.0.k1m2t5a3245k242qmfp75spjkv.avts.\r\n    ----------------------------------------\r\n    Record Name . . . . . : 9.a.c.e.x-0.19-430f5091.531.1518.1b8d.2f4a.210.0.k1m2t5a3245k242qmfp75spjkv.avts.\r\n    Record Type . . . . . : 1\r\n    Time To Live  . . . . : 289\r\n    Data Length . . . . . : 4\r\n    Section . . . . . . . : Answer\r\n    A (Host) Record . . . : 127.0 .0.16\r\n\r\n\r\n'
```

From this output I am interested in the values for `A (Host) Record` and `Record Name` which are `127.0.0.16` and `9.a.c.e.x-0.19-430f5091.531.1518.1b8d.2f4a.210.0.k1m2t5a3245k242qmfp75spjkv.avts.` respectively.

How would I do it in Python?

Comment: `output.split(' ')` ? (Edit: after your edit, this is not valid)

Answer (score 16):

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("ipconfig /displaydns", shell=True)
result = {}
for row in output.split('\n'):
    if ': ' in row:
        key, value = row.split(': ')
        result[key.strip(' .')] = value.strip()

print(result)
print(result['A (Host) Record'])
```

gives:

```
{'A (Host) Record': '127.0 .0.16', 'Data Length': '4', 'Section': 'Answer', 'Record Name': '9.a.c.e.x-0.19-430f5091.531.1518.1b8d.2f4a.210.0.k1m2t5a3245k242qmfp75spjkv.avts.', 'Time To Live': '289', 'Record Type': '1'}
127.0 .0.16
```

---

Another solution would be to:
(when i thought of this in my head, i thought it would be more compact.. it wasn't but anyway, it's a different way of calling the external command where you get control of the errors and output (you can differntiate the two))

```
import subprocess
cmdpipe = subprocess.Popen("ipconfig /displaydns", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
result = {}
for row in cmdpipe.stdout.readline():
    if ': ' in row:
        key, value = row.split(': ')
        result[key.strip(' .')] = value.strip()

# You need to close the file handles, as they will stay open "forever" otherwise.
cmdpipe.stdout.close()
cmdpipe.stderr.close()

print(result)
print(result['A (Host) Record'])
```

I'll also add that using `shell=True` [might be dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/929999) especially when combined with user-input. It does add some "hidden magic" to make some things easier or more user-natural. But in most cases you will want to do `subprocess.Popen(["ipconfig", "/displaydns"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` instead.

Comment: @user2253876 You're welcome, don't forget to mark your answer (it gives me pleasure inside) :)